# Why are we interested in total variation and how does it tie into its integral definition?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, total-variation, signed-measures

I am studying measure theory and had a few questions. In the text I am using, it defines total variation of a measure $\nu$ as

$$|\nu| = \nu^+ + \nu^-$$
My first question is why are we interested in this quantity to begin with? Secondly, the text claims that the above implies $\nu$ is of the form $\nu(E) = \int_E f d|\nu|$, for any measurable set $E$. I cannot see how this integral definition follows the total variation definition. Lastly, the text claims the inequality $|\nu(E)| \leq |\nu|(E)$ is obvious, but I cannot quite see how. One last question I have is one of notation. I see notation such as $g(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu})$, what does this mean exactly?

Thank you.

Comment: Unwind the definition of $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$, in terms of a Hahn decomposition for $\nu$. Also, for your later questions, you should continue reading till you see the stuff about Radon-Nikodym theorem.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I understand we obtain positive and negative sets for $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ by the Han decomposition, but I am still a little lost as to how this ties into integration.

Answer (score 3):

(1) Why are we interested in the total variation?

Firstly, because of (2) and (3), below.  We can often prove things about signed measures using this.

(2) Why is $\nu(E) = \int_E f d|\nu|$?

Hahn decomposition.

(3) Why is $|\nu(E)| \leq |\nu|(E)$?

Use your solution to (2).

(4) I doubt you often see $g(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu})$, that is a function $g$ evaluated on a Radon-Nikodym derivative.  But you *do* often see $g\;\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$, that is a function $g$ multiplied by a Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Comment: Thank you. So is (2) essentially saying we take the integral of $f$ over positive and negative sets (with respect to $\nu$)? I assume $(3)$ then follows by a simple triangle inequality. I see (4) in the context of "if $g \in L^1(\nu)$ then $g(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}) \in L^1(\mu)$"